# RecordViewForm not displaying Records

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm having trouble using the lightning:recordViewForm component.
My problem is that i can see my tasklist in console but its is not diplaying within the recordViewForm and not showing any error. 
Please , anyone who faced the same issue?

Here is My component Code :

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller ="MyInboxController" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.getTasks}" value="{!this}"  />
<!-- get the list of opportunity by calling the lightning controller  -->
<!-- an attribute to store the list of opportunities -->
<aura:attribute name="TaskList" type="List"/>
<!-- rectangle -->
<lightning:card title="Tasks">
    <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
        <!-- apex:repeat -->
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.TaskList}" var="task">
            <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="{!task.Id}" objectApiName="Task">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Id" /> 
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="OwnerId" />               
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Priority" />   
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Status" /> 
            </lightning:recordViewForm>
        </aura:iteration>
    </p>
</lightning:card>
```

And Helper Code :

```
({
fetchTasks : function(component,event,helper) {
    // define my action : 
        // call the method getOpportunites from our apex controller (auraenabled)
        var action = component.get("c.getTasksApex");
        var opportunityId= component.get("v.recordId");
        action.setParams({
            opportunityId: opportunityId
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){
            var state=response.getState();
            //state can be success error incomplete
        if (state=='SUCCESS'){

            var tasklist =response.getReturnValue();
            component.set("v.Tasklist",tasklist);
            console.log(tasklist);
        } else {
            alert('Error in getting data');
        }                    
    });

 // to start my action 
 $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

})

Im also using an application :

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
<c:MyInboxComponent recordId="0061w000018TieYAAS" />
```

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to SFSE. Could you please edit your question to include code selections inline as text, rather than screenshots? You can paste code, select it, and press Ctrl-K or click `{}` in the toolbar to ensure it is formatted properly.

Comment: Hello Sara, in general your component looks ok. Please update your helper section, because it has Component code in it. Did you try to check results returned by Apex Controller?

Comment: @ytiq  Yeah i did try it and it looks good too. I updated the helper code sorry

Comment: I remembered. Task object is not supported by UI API( You can check list of supported Objects here [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm). So you should probably consider other options.

Comment: um , I changed it to opportunity and made another soql for my controller but same problem in console it is displayed but in my page not  , only the title that changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Task` with `lightning:outputField` which is **not** a supported object for that component.

Refer below from documentation for [`lightning:outputField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:outputField/documentation):

> For supported objects, see the [User Interface API Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm).

And if you refer the User Interface API Developer Guide, `Task` is not a supported object.

Your option here is to utilize other component which supports `Task`.

Comment: um , I changed it to opportunity and made another soql for my controller but same problem in console it is displayed but in my page not , only the title that changed.

Comment: You need to use the same attribute name `TaskList` as declared on component. Currently you are setting the value on `Tasklist`, notice the lower case L.

Comment: Yeah that was it , didnt notice ! Thank you , i didnt know about the supported object though.

Answer (score 1):

You have attribute called `TaskList`. But in helper you are setting `Tasklist` (note lower case `l`).
`TaskList` will never be populated with values.

Note that Aura Components are case sensitive (see [Release Notes Spring '15](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring15/release-notes/rn_lightning_case.htm) for reference).

As @Jayant Das mentioned, [`lightning:recordViewForm`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordViewForm) component does not work with Activity and Task objects.